# Browser scrollbar width

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, I admit I am stuck and I have already spent way too much time on this. jQuery scroll bars are great...when they work. When they don't they leave you in a position I am now.

I have tried almost every jquery scrollbar that I could find (the first three pages in google and on jQuery's plugin pages) and everyone caused their own unique problems with the website I am building. So many problems that I have now wasted three days with this.

My question is, is there a way in jQuery were I can just change the width of the browser scrollbar? That's all I really need the plugins for...is to make it just a bit larger for touchscreens.

I am at the point of being desperate and any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Touchscreens don't use scrollbars. That's the benefit of touch.

Comment: @DA , yes normally, but my company wants a scrollbar, so I have to make one work. I'm working a touch screen kiosking system geared towed old people and if they don't see one they'll freak.

Comment: I want a pet unicorn. But reality keeps getting in the way. (Good luck getting your company to understand reality...I know that can be a futile task sometimes...we've all been there having to deal with ridiculous requirements). If you absolutely must have a scrollbar, then don't rely on the browser--as that is often out of your control. Instead build your own javascript based ones manually. A huge pain, but will at least make the bosses happy.

Comment: Did you given [that](http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/) a try?

Comment: That said, if you have the ambition, try explaining to them how their request isn't applicable to the medium. Have them take out their iphone and show you an app or a web site that uses scrollbars to navigate on a touch device.

Comment: There is not a way to do that.  If you always need a scroll bar, you'll need to create it yourself.  As a designer, though, I generally stay away from changing the default behavior of the browser.  If a mobile or touch browser has no scroll bars or a very tiny one (some do), just work with it.  You might try appealing to the company and explaining why it wouldn't be a good idea to do it.

Comment: @DA, I have tried pretty much everything I can think of and I just don't have the time to create my own custom one. I've tried every plugin I can find and even tried modifying them to make them work, but none want to work. Do you know of any really simple bare bones ones that might work or I can work with? They gave me an ultimatum...make it work or you're gone...

Comment: @kevin628, I've been trying to work with it. I have tried every plugin I can find and can make it change(disappear) however none want to work with me. And as much as I hate this take how they have the interface set up, they do have a very good reason for the scrollbar and does make scene to have one.

Comment: You could make a js one in a few hours. You spent days trying to get plugins to work already so cut your losses and get to work on your own. I agree with you though - I am often forced to do the totally illogical because a client demands it and my job is to slave like an idiot without questioning or pointing out the client's stupidity. So you have to make a huge scrollbar for the old on touch devices. No, you cannot just change scrollbar style. Even if you could, touch devices would probably hide it anyhow.

Comment: @zazvorniki an ultimatum? For what it's worth, that sounds like a horrific place to work. Anyways, there is no guaranteed way to modify browser scrollbars. They are 'owned' by the browser/OS. Some browsers give you some leeway to modify them, some don't let you modify them at all. The only SURE way to create a custom scrollbar is to make your own.